# Local Postgres database --- FATAL password for user "postgres" -- but I know the password. What do I do?

Tags: postgresql, admin

I just started using and learning Postgres here.

When I first installed and set it up, it looks like there was only one "password" I had to configure and I saved it in a password manager.

I believe this is the "master password" but I've used pgAdmin 4 exclusively as a client to manage the local server (and databases on it).

Now it wants to me enter a password (day 2) for 'postgres' --- I thought I knew this and that it was the same as the "master password" -- but apparently not. What is going on, and how do I get back in? How do I prevent this in the future?

Comment: You could try to reset your password if that is possible. I don't know a lot about postgressql, so idk. I found https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-reset-password/

Comment: Seemed handy but still not working. Literally a fresh install and I haven't done much. Can't even say I forgot the password --- something wonky going on .... mm. Next time I'll set up a second 'SA' user to lessen that BS.

Comment: Actually this worked. I forgot one hidden line in the middle that WASN'T commented out in the config file. Thanks!

Comment: You can self answer your question with more details, as I don't know enough about postgressql to answer your question.